# TicketManager class in Java

Tags: java

I'm reading the famous Clean Code book of Robert C. Martin so I'm trying to refactor some of my latest code as exercise.
I feel like the method `getTicket` breaks the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) as it does too many things (get the ticket, check if it's still valid, get a new one...).

On the other hand I don't see any room for improvements. What do you think?

```
@Component
public class TicketManager {
    
    private static final long TICKET_EXPIRATION_TIME_MIN = 5;
    private Map<String, TicketHolder> ticketWrapperMap;
    
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        ticketWrapperMap = new HashMap<String, TicketManager.TicketHolder>();
    }
    
    public String getTicket(String userId) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(userId);
        
        final Instant now = Instant.now();
        
        TicketHolder ticketHolder = Optional.ofNullable(ticketWrapperMap.get(userId)).orElse(generateNewTicketHolder(userId, now));
        
        if (isTicketValid(ticketHolder, now)) {
            return ticketHolder.getTicket();
        }
        
        return generateNewTicketHolder(userId, now).getTicket();
    }
    
    private TicketHolder generateNewTicketHolder(String userId, Instant now) {
        return ticketWrapperMap.put(userId, TicketHolder.of(now, generateNewTicket(userId)));
    }
    
    private boolean isTicketValid(TicketHolder ticketHolder, Instant now) {
        return ticketHolder != null && ticketHolder.getCreationTime().plus(Duration.ofMinutes(TICKET_EXPIRATION_TIME_MIN)).isAfter(now);
    }
    
    private String generateNewTicket(String userId) {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class TicketHolder {
        
        Instant creationTime;
        String ticket;
        
        private TicketHolder(Instant ldt, String ticket) {
            this.creationTime = ldt;
            this.ticket = ticket;
        }
        
        public static TicketHolder of(Instant ldt, String ticket) {
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(ldt);
            Preconditions.checkArgument(ticket != null && !ticket.isBlank());
            
            return new TicketHolder(ldt, ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Note many people view these principles with skepticism.

Comment: @user253751 skeptical about what?

Comment: @Savlon whether following the rules is more useful than harmful, of course.

Comment: @user253751 ahh true. I guess it comes down to how you see them. Despite their name, I don’t see them as rules, I see them more as guides than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get a valid ticket if one exists, otherwise generate a new one" is a useful convenience function, but it really does two things that, I believe, can usefully be done separately - "get a valid ticket if one exists" and "generate a new ticket". I would suggest creating those functions and making the current `getTicket` into a wrapper for those, perhaps looking something like `getExistingTicket(userId).orElseGet(() -> generateNewTicket(userId))`

I also think the logic of `getTicket` gets a bit muddied in places. You fetch a ticket from your list of known tickets, and if you don't find one you generate a new one. Now that you have a ticket, you check if it's valid. If it is, you return it, if not, you generate a new one and return that.
My issue here is that that code, while it *is* working fine and free of bugs, it *looks* like it has a bug in it. See, since the code is written to explicitly check the validity of a newly generated ticket, that implies to a reader that a newly generated ticket *might not be valid* (yes, you and I both know it is, but I didn't know that at first, and neither will anyone else when reading the code for the first time). And then you go on to generate and return a new ticket without checking if it's valid. It'd be clearer to check for validity *before* generating a new one, like

```java
TicketHolder ticketHolder = ticketWrapperMap.get(userId);

if (ticketHolder != null && isTicketValid(ticketHolder, now)) {
    return ticketHolder.getTicket();
} else {
    return generateNewTicketHolder(userId, now).getTicket();
}
```

or, if you have *strong* opinions on the use of `null`

```java
return Optional
    .ofNullable(ticketWrapperMap.get(userId))
    .filter(t -> isTicketValid(t, now))
    .orElseGet(() -> generateNewTicketHolder(userId, now))
    .getTicket();
```

I also find it a bit weird to not expose the expiration time to callers. Might the caller need to know when a ticket will expire? It might be better to return the entire `TicketHolder` rather than just the `String`

On a related note, I'm not sold on the name `TicketHolder`. A `String` with no associated `TicketHolder` isn't really a ticket at all - you have no idea if it's valid, so you can't use it, right? So, I'd actually argue that these `TicketHolder`s aren't *holders* for tickets, but are, themselves, `Ticket`s.

Finally, while "manager" classes do have their uses, it's worth taking care to make sure it's clear what is the responsibility of the manager and the managee. Consider what *exactly* should be the responsibility of a `TicketManager` as opposed to `Ticket`s themselves, and perhaps giving `TickerManager` a name that makes that clearer. Some things to consider might be:

- Might different managers have different criteria for when a ticket is considered valid? If not, validity is a property of a ticket rather than of a manager, meaning `TicketManager::isTicketValid` should probably be `Ticket::isValid`
- Do different managers have different ways to turn a user ID into a ticket string? If not, `TicketManager::generateNewTicket` could probably be part of `Ticket` instead, and you may even want to consider whether `Ticket::new` should take a user ID as its parameter instead of the ticket string

Comment: I agree pretty much on everything. Thanks! The only thing is that I wanted the method getTicket to be transparent to the caller, the caller doesn't need to know if TicketManager is returnig a new ticket or an existing one hence getTicket encapsulates the double logic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In short: no, it does not follow single responsability principle to the letter. Problem is not so much the `getTicket` but the `generateNewTicket` method. This means your class is responsible for both storing and generating tickets. The latter method should be refactored behind a `TicketSupplier` interface, which gets provided to `TicketManager` using dependency inversion.

You could also refactor the ticket validation behind a `TicketValidator` interface, but we're chasing diminishing returns here. It may or may not be of any benefit to split this class into three parts immediately. If possible, you could just let it be and split it up when an actual need for extension arises.

Now to the important part. :)

You are abusing Optionals. They are not intended to be a replacement for if-else statements and null-checks inside your own code. There is nothing wrong in if-statements and null checks. They should not be avoided just because Optionals have a more fashionable image. In my opinion using optionals like this just makes the code much harder to follow. Optionals are intended for [declaring the possibility of null in public method return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional/23464794#23464794) *only*. You are supposed to know what your own private code does so no need to declare Optionals here. You are also making unnecessary null-checks in your private methods. `TicketHolder` is never null when you call `isTicketValid` so the null-check is redundant.

The `generateNewTicketHolder` seems like it has a side effect that is not very clearly described in the method name. It both creates a `TicketHolder` instance and stores it in the `ticketWrapperMap`. That dual functionality might also be considered as breaking single responsibility.

Comment: hehe you're probably right on Optional abusing :)